# Laravel Exception with Livewire Does not Return JSON

Tags: php, laravel

I would like to return a json that can be read in Livewire and dispatched into notification

Livewire

```
public function update(AgencyAgent $agent){
    $input = $this->validate();
    $input['agent_id'] = $agent->id;
    $request = new Request($input);

    $controllerAgencyAgent = new AgencyAgentController();
    $res = $controllerAgencyAgent->update(request:$request,user:Auth::user());

    if($res->status()!=200){
        $this->dispatch('show-toast',['status' => 'error', 'message' => $res->getData()->message]);
        return;
    }

    $this->dispatch('show-toast',['status' => 'success', 'message' => $res->getData()->message]);
    $this->closeModal();
}
```

Controller

```
public function update(Request $request, User $user): JsonResponse
{
    // Check admin/support
    if($this->hasManagedRole){
        throw new InvalidOwnership;
    }
}
```

Handler (Exception)

```
public function render($request, \Throwable $exception) {

    if ($exception instanceof InvalidOwnership) {
        return response()->json(
            [
                'success' => false,
                'message' => __('You have no access'),
            ],
            400
        );
    }
}
```

You could see that I need to return json but instead of json, it is returning a dd format like this. I have set debug as false and env as production in the .env file.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Because the HTTP response status code is `400` it represents an error therefore Livewire JavaScript Client dumps it out like that you need to return it in success code `200` if you don't need Livewire JavaScript to dump it out.

```
return response()->json([
    'success' => false,
    'message' => __('You have no access')
]);
```

Comment: I have used JSON before but when the function nested we need to return that value to the parent which is complicated. We develop both web and mobile app. API is working with throw, returning JSON while livewire does not. Is there any Livewire setting that can be achieved to handle throw into json?

Comment: Unfortunately, there are no settings to achieve that.
Your response from the backend returned in JSON but the Livewire JavaScript Client
Dump it out.
I think you don't need to throw the exception when using Livewire just use attributes to send the error message from the Livewire Component class to the component blade file